# Bot Framework Slack Message Reaction Not Received

Tags: asp.net, azure, botframework, slack

I'm using the Bot Framework v4 based on the Enterprise Bot Template (found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-enterprise-template-overview?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) as a base for my chatbot. The bot is hosted on Azure with all the required services.

I have connected it to a Slack app and everything is working.
I have registered for "reaction_added" event in the "Event Subscriptions" within Slack.

What I'm trying to do is to detect and act on a Slack message reaction (e.g. thumbsup on a message) from within the chatbot code but I'm not getting a message for any reaction from the user.

The OnTurnAsync doesn't seem to get any call or activity for such events.

Does anyone know what's going on or how to receive these events?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to be sure, do you handle all activities type? I don't remember if the Bot Framework is able to catch those reactions and in that case, the kind of activity it would be

Comment: Essentially I check for context.Activity != null. But in any case, I don't see a call to OnTurnAysnc at all.

Comment: Have you added "reaction_added" or "reaction_removed" to the Slack side of the app?

Comment: Doing a bit more digging, it looks like the bot should respond to a user adding a reaction using slack's reaction.get event subscript, HOWEVER, it appears slack has removed that from the list of bot event subscriptions when you're setting up your bot.

Comment: hmm...that's strange. I wonder why.